# Derby database throws error while querying from IJ CLI tool - ERROR 42X05: Table/View 'CAL_RECURRING_ENTRY' does not exist

Tags: sql, database, schema, derby

My `derby` database name is `data` and my schema name is `CICD`. After I'd opened up `IJ` cli tool, I have connected to the database which is running on `port` - `11377` with the following command, -

```
ij> connect 'jdbc:derby://localhost:11377/data';
```

After connecting to my database I have to perform some table updates. I'd tried executing the following query,

```
ij> update CAL_RECURRING_ENTRY set name='Newly added descirption' where id='18cedfc9-05d4-24e2-ff7a-d34fd9f3d39c';
```

which is failing with,

> ERROR 42X05: Table/View 'CAL_RECURRING_ENTRY' does not exist.

What do I missing over here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use `schema_name.table_name` while querying

Try executing the following query, it should work.

```
update CICD.CAL_RECURRING_ENTRY set name='Newly added description' where id='18cedfc9-05d4-24e2-ff7a-d34fd9f3d39c';
```